# What is the best way to organize the functions in different JS files?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file called `common.js` in which I have implemented some general functions that I would need many times in the whole project.

Sometimes the functions name in `common.js` are same as other JS file that I might include on a page that would create a conflict and the latest definition will be used which is depends on the order of inclusion of file.

I assume that the way I am handling things is wrong; would like to know how should I handle this kind of situation to have a better readability and flow of code.

Comment: you should name space your functions. try something like below  
var namespace = namespace || {
   functionA : function() {
   }, 
  functionB: function() {
  }
}

call the functions as namespace.functionA();

Comment: Simple solution, don't duplicate function names. Function names are used to identify a specific function so if you have multiple functions that use the same name, the last one the browser reads is the one it will call as you are overwriting the first one the browser reads. Browsers read like us. From top left, to the right and down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Namespacing your function as @Praveen said would solve your problem, however I strongly suggest you to look into http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should namespace them, maybe like Utils or something, you will need to refactor but it is best practice to have things namespaced.

you could easily do something like this -

https://jsfiddle.net/2rjv6qqu/

```
var utils = {
    foo: function () {
        alert("utils foo");
        this.bar();
    },
    bar: function () {
        alert("utils bar");
    }
}

var another = {
    foo: function () {
        alert("Another foo");
        this.bar();
    },
    bar: function () {
        alert("Another bar");
    }
}

utils.foo();
another.foo();
```

This is a super basic example of namespacing.